# How to add Split button in jquery UI dialog button section

Tags: jquery, split-button

How to add Split button in jquery UI dialog button section.

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
position: ['center'],
modal: true,
width: 'auto',
height: 'auto',
buttons: {
        'Save' : function() {       
            $(this).dialog('close');

                  I need to add split button in this place.
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks & Regards,
kathir

Comment: You mean http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/button/splitbutton.html

Comment: yes, I need the same split button